# Join multiple lines into single line

Tags: bash, shell

I have below piece of code, that created for Snowflake uploading.

"3bd3ce4c-8839-4d55-bca7-8ad27cddf7f6"|"2e0636c6-400b-4cfe-b63b-a14a0de723f8"|"21713280"|"eb38a6a4-6b0a-496a-b2f7-63c33b21a706"|"We do not allow SSH into Erlang"|"03fb9da3-98a1-4cbe-8aef-d4f9d28e7065"|"2021-06-2 11:32:19.257000"|"2021-06-28 11:32:19.257000"
"3bd3ce4c-8839-4d55-bca7-8ad27cddf7f6"|"2e0636c6-400b-4cfe-b63b-a14a0de723f8"|"21713299"|"7ce284d9-2dd3-47e2-b9da-f3a20250efe5"|"BDSA-2017-3658
EPMD port is not exposed.

CVE-2011-0766
We do not allow SSH in Erlang.

CVE-2020-35733
The certificate is controlled by our deployment team.

BDSA-2021-0916 (CVE-2021-29221)
Local access to the machine is limited to authorized personnel."|"03fb9da3-98a1-4cbe-8aef-d4f9d28e7065"|"2021-06-28 11:31:08.743000"|"2021-06-28 11:31:08.743000"
"3bd3ce4c-8839-4d55-bca7-8ad27cddf7f6"|"2e0636c6-400b-4cfe-b63b-a14a0de723f8"|"21713300"|"f496b0b2-23a5-4826-8455-d754889bae1c"|"We do not allow SSH into Erlang."|"03fb9da3-98a1-4cbe-8aef-d4f9d28e7065"|"2021-06-28 11:29:43.454000"|"2021-06-28 11:29:43.454000"
"8156bcee-eae2-4025-8c22-b70acc57f55f"|"65360414-0bd9-499e-ad0b-7eccde3c579d"|"11298717"|"1ad0aeb8-8135-491d-b28a-5f425afb9ca0"|"BDSA-2022-1742 does not affect used by ESP
embedded Tomcat

https://nice.app.blackduck.com/api/vulnerabilities/BDSA-2022-1742/overview

This vulnerability only affects applications that happen to use form authentication based on example web application bundled with Tomcat."|"90252330-c1a7-48fb-9d99-4af8f60dbefb"|"2022-06-24 14:29:26.272000"|"2022-07-06 17:25:50.882646"

How I can join these lines into a single line?
I try remove enters by this command:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if /[^"\n]$/' $file  > /tmp/$file
```

I need combine multiple lines in a file to a single line, but only for splitted lines. First line, that started from 3bd3ce4c-8839-4d55-bca7-8ad27cddf7f6 and ended with 11:32:19.257000 - is ok, but second is not. I need fix only multiple lines. Thanks Stas

Comment: Is the entire "piece of code" what you want to join into a single like or some subset of it? Unclear.

Comment: Hi., This is single line from file and I need join only lines like this. All other need be remained

Comment: Don't add links or images, just text, and make sure to format you input, output, and code as Code Blocks (as your code currently is and your previous sample input was), see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Make sure to provide sample input AND the expected output given that input. Best I can tell you only have sample input in your question so far - we can't test a potential solution with just input and no output to compare the result to.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s", $0} END{print ""}' file
    "8156bcee-eae2-4025-8c22-b70acc57f55f"|"65360414-0bd9-499e-ad0b-7eccde3c579d"|"11298717"|"1ad0aeb8-8135-491d-b28a-5f425afb9ca0"|"BDSA-2022-1742 does not affect used by ESP embedded Tomcathttps://nice.app.blackduck.com/api/vulnerabilities/BDSA-2022-1742/overviewThis vulnerability only affects applications that happen to use form authentication based on example web application bundled with Tomcat."|"90252330-c1a7-48fb-9d99-4af8f60dbefb"|"2022-06-24 14:29:26.272000"|"2022-07-06 17:25:50.882646"
```

or maybe you'd prefer to put a blank between joined lines:

```
$ awk 'NF{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=" "} END{print ""}' file
    "8156bcee-eae2-4025-8c22-b70acc57f55f"|"65360414-0bd9-499e-ad0b-7eccde3c579d"|"11298717"|"1ad0aeb8-8135-491d-b28a-5f425afb9ca0"|"BDSA-2022-1742 does not affect used by ESP  embedded Tomcat https://nice.app.blackduck.com/api/vulnerabilities/BDSA-2022-1742/overview This vulnerability only affects applications that happen to use form authentication based on example web application bundled with Tomcat."|"90252330-c1a7-48fb-9d99-4af8f60 dbefb"|"2022-06-24 14:29:26.272000"|"2022-07-06 17:25:50.882646"
```

Comment: Hi Ed. Thanks for you answer. You solution is joined all lines into my file. I try find solution, when some line have this structure I need align it to line and remain all others

Comment: Best I can tell my answer does exactly what you asked for in your question. If you don't show us what you want with the example in your question then you're leaving it to us to guess at what you want. If your question doesn't adequately describe your needs then [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output, and your attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't just re-edit your code, though, describe your needs more clearly and add sample input and expected output that we can test a potential solution against to get a simple pass/fail result.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
paste -sd' ' file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jot -c - 65 126 |
```

- single space

> ```
> mawk 7 ORS=' '
> ```

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ %
```

- gap-less

> ```
> gawk 3 ORS=
> ```

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ %
```

- **`printf`-free approach for gap-less plus trailing new-line**

> ```
> mawk -F'^$' 'END { print RS } !(ORS=_)'
> ```

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
%
```

- sep'ed by the Apple-logo `U+F8FF` (``) (wouldn't print correctly on `Windows/Linux/Android/DOS/BeOS…`

> ```
> nawk 5 ORS='\357\243\277'
> ```

```
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

- using themselves as `ORS` as an unconventional way up to double up everything :

> ```
> mawk2 'ORS = $_'
> ```

```
AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMMNNOOPPQQRRSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZ[[\\]]^^__``
aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~
```

- make 4 extra copies each instead of just 1

> ```
> nawk '(OFS = $_)(NF = 5)' ORS= | gsed -zE 's/.{65}/&\n/g'
> ```

``````
AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDEEEEEFFFFFGGGGGHHHHHIIIIIJJJJJKKKKKLLLLLMMMMM
NNNNNOOOOOPPPPPQQQQQRRRRRSSSSSTTTTTUUUUUVVVVVWWWWWXXXXXYYYYYZZZZZ
[[[[[\\\\\]]]]]^^^^^_____`````aaaaabbbbbcccccdddddeeeeefffffggggg
hhhhhiiiiijjjjjkkkkklllllmmmmmnnnnnooooopppppqqqqqrrrrrsssssttttt
uuuuuvvvvvwwwwwxxxxxyyyyyzzzzz{{{{{|||||}}}}}~~~~~
``````

- have them increase in # of copies as function of input row order :

> ```
> gawk '(OFS = ORS = $_) (NF = int(sqrt( NR )))'
> ```

```````
AABBCCDDDEEEFFFGGGHHHIIIIJJJJKKKKLLLLMMMMNNNNOOOOPPPPPQQQQQ
RRRRRSSSSSTTTTTUUUUUVVVVVWWWWWXXXXXYYYYYYZZZZZZ[[[[[[\\\\\\
]]]]]]^^^^^^______``````aaaaaabbbbbbccccccdddddddeeeeeeefffffff
ggggggghhhhhhhiiiiiiijjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllmmmmmmmnnnnnnnooooooo
pppppppqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrssssssssttttttttuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvwwwwwwww
xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{||||||||}}}}}}}}~~~~~~~~
```````

Comment: @JamesRisner : its' the correct question - i was showcasing different join seps, and that `ORS` can be used in less conventional ways other than just "new line". I used the 2nd quadrant of bytes instead of OP's since it was less clear to me which exact lines OP wanted to join together, and with what, since joining with a comma, with a space, no delimiter at all, or a dash etc, could be optimized via different approaches